# API para leitura OCR(Reconhecimento Optico de Caracteres) com ANDROID

Tags: java, android, ocr

Boa noite pessoal, gostaria de saber se alguém conhece ou se já trabalhou com alguma Api que forneça soluções de leitura OCR para plataforma Mobile.

Se possível listar algumas pra mim. Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Em java, até uns 3 anos atras, não achei nada open source / free. O que eu achei, era algumas implementações em C/C++ que fazia-se o biding por jni, creio que no android de para fazer tranquilamente o mesmo. Vou acompanhar as respostas por aqui também.

Comment: Existem algumas libs sim, o pessoal costumar usar muito o `Tesseract`. Nunca usei, então não consigo dar grandes detalhes... Talvez esse link possa te ajudar: http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/

Comment: Vlw pessoal, foram de grande ajuda, iniciarei as pesquisas sobre essas implementações em C/C++ e sobre o Tesseract.